How to calculate a multiple integral over a triangular region
I am having trouble computing the multiple integral
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} e^{\frac{1}{2}(x + y)^2} \, dy\, dx
\end{equation}
Because integrating $e^{\frac{1}{2}(x + y)^2}$ with respect to $x$ or $y$ is a bad idea, my overall idea is to change the coordinate system. My first idea was to convert this integral to polar coordinates. However, this isn't a good fit with the $(x + y)^2$ in the exponent; if it were $x^2 + y^2$ instead, it would work.
My second idea was to use a linear transformation. Specifically, I observed that the graph of the region of integration looks like

Then, because the upper-bounding line is $x + y = 1$, I was motivated to change the coordinates from $(x, y)$ to $(u, v)$ where $u = x + y$. I didn't really know what to set $v$ to, so I just set $v = x$.
Now, I would need to find the new limits of integration using the $uv$ coordinate system. I know that $0 \leq u \leq 1$, but I don't know how to bound $v$ so that the resulting region is the same as the original one. Because $v = x$, I initially just used the bounds $0 \leq v \leq 1$, but this results in the following incorrect domain of integration:

I feel like the current issue with my attempted solution is a poor choice of the $v$-coordinate, but I do not know what I should have it be instead. Can someone provide hints or a solution to this problem?

You are quite close - it's a good thought!
Continuing the geometric intuition - you want to represent the points on the line $x+y =u$ with positive $x$ and $y$ coordinates. For positive $u$, observe that $(\frac{u}{2}, \frac{u}{2})$ will always lie on the line
We can use the line joining $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{u}{2}, \frac{u}{2})$ as a reference. For an arbitrary $(x,y)$ on the line, let the angle made by joining $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$ and this reference line be $v$. Can you express $x$ and $y$ in $u$ and $v$? The range of $v$ will always be $(-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4})$

You can do it using polar coordinates. In fact,\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}e^{\frac12(x+y)^2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{1/(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))}\rho e^{\frac12\rho^2(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))^2}\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{e}-1}{(\cos(\theta )+\sin(\theta))^2}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\sqrt e-1.\end{align}
